# Ethernet not working in HP Laptop Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, ethernet, hp, realtek

I have HP 240 G7, after installing Ubuntu 18.04, my wi-fi and ethernet all not working. After I searching some solution, I got that my driver didn't compatible with my HW (realtek).
So, I try to update the driver (regarding the tutorial from internet), well wi-fi working now, but ethernet still not working. 
when I ping google in terminal:

`ping: google.com: Name or service not known`

Comment: Ethernet devices are very well supported. Unless it's some brand new or exotic chip, it's almost guaranteed to have support (correct drivers) out of the box. Please edit and post the line regarding the Ethernet device from `lspci`. Meanwhile check cable.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved. I think when I updating the driver, it was worked and allready ready to use. 
Then, about my problem, its about my IP is binded with my ex laptop's mac address. So, its not about the driver or HW problem. But its about my IP and local configurations. It was solved by internal sys admin at my office. Thanks :)